# MATLAB: Changing the line properties of a loaded figure?

Tags: matlab, plot, edit, matlab-figure

I've got a very simple question, for MATLAB users:

If I load a figure file (.fig) with the load command, is there any way to change the plotted lines properties from the command line? (width, color, marker, etc.)

PD: The first two options according to the information in *[Defining the Color of Lines for Plotting
On this page…](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/bqsxy_a-1.html)* only work if you use the plot command. Apparently they are useless if you load the figure.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can get handles for all line objects on current figure with [FINDOBJ](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/findobj.html) function:

```
hline = findobj(gcf, 'type', 'line');
```

Then you can change some property for all the line objects:

```
set(hline,'LineWidth',3)
```

or just for some of them :

```
set(hline(1),'LineWidth',3) 
set(hline(2:3),'LineStyle',':') 
idx = [4 5];
set(hline(idx),'Marker','*')
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to manipulate objects in a figure, you need to have access to their handles. If you create a figure using plotting functions, these will return handles to you. When you are opening a figure, as is your case, you need to follow a graphic objects tree to find the handle to the specific element you want to manipulate.

[This page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/learn_matlab/f3-15974.html) has information about the structure of graphics objects.

The path to the handles you want will depend on your figure, but, as an example, if your figure was created using a simple `plot` command, this would be one way to change line properties:

```
x = 0:0.1:2;
plot(x,sin(x));

fig = gcf % get a handle to the current figure
% get handles to the children of that figure: the axes in this case
ax = get(fig,'children') 
% get handles to the elements in the axes: a single line plot here
h = get(ax,'children') 
% manipulate desired properties of the line, e.g. line width
set(h,'LineWidth',3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll take into consideration. However I find the alternative above, more intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @yuk answer, if you have a **legend drawn as well**,

```
hline = findobj(gcf, 'type', 'line');
```

will return `N x 3` lines (or more precisely - `lines plotted + 2x lines in legend`). **I will here look only at the case when all the lines that are plotted are also in the legend.**

The sequencing is weird:
in case of 5 lines (let us note them `1 to 5`) plotted and the legend added, you will have

```
hline:
1 : 5 th line (mistical)    
2 : 5 th line (in legend)
3 : 4 th line (mistical)    
4 : 4 th line (in legend)
5 : 3 th line (mistical)    
6 : 3 th line (in legend)
7 : 2 th line (mistical)    
8 : 2 th line (in legend)
9 : 1 th line (mistical)    
10: 1 th line (in legend)
11: 5 th line (in plot)
12: 4 th line (in plot)
13: 3 th line (in plot)
14: 2 th line (in plot)
15: 1 th line (in plot)
```

As a solution (friday evening procrastination) I made this little baby:

**Solution 1:** if you don't want to reset the legend

Detect if there is a legend and how many lines are plotted:

```
hline = findobj(gcf, 'type', 'line');
isThereLegend=(~isempty(findobj(gcf,'Type','axes','Tag','legend')))

if(isThereLegend)
    nLines=length(hline)/3
else
    nLines=length(hline)
end
```

For each line find the right handles and do the stuff for that line (it will apply also to the corresponding legend line)

```
for iterLine=1:nLines
    mInd=nLines-iterLine+1
    if(isThereLegend)
        set(hline([(mInd*2-1) (mInd*2) (2*nLines+mInd)]),'LineWidth',iterLine) 
    else
    set(hline(mInd),'LineWidth',iterLine)     
    end
end
```

This makes every `i-th` line with the `width=i` and here you can add the automated property changing;

**Solution 2:** Keep it simple

Get rid of the legend, take care of the lines, reset legend.

```
legend off
hline = findobj(gcf, 'type', 'line');
nLines=length(hline)

for iterLine=1:nLines
    mInd=nLines-iterLine+1
    set(hline(mInd),'LineWidth',iterLine)     
end
legend show
```

This might not be suitable for situations when the legend must be placed in some speciffic place etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just right click on the line in the viewer, and change the properties there. This also changes the corresponding 'legend' entry (at least it does in 2014b).